# ROS2 most appropiate way for central data storage

Tags: ros2, parameter, parameter-server

I am currently working on a ROS2 project that includes various components, such as a behavior tree, sensor processing, and a GUI. I'm in need of a central data storage solution where each component can access, read, and write data.

So far, I've tried the following methods:

- Storing data and setting up a ROS2 node as a central parameter server. Other nodes subscribe to `/parameter_events` and update their internal variables accordingly. However, I've encountered issues where some messages are lost, resulting in nodes not updating. Additionally, some data is complex, making it feel inappropriate to store as parameters.
- I set up a local SQLite3 database to store all the data, allowing all nodes to read and write easily. However, I'm looking for a way to have a reactive callback whenever data changes, rather than polling for updates. It seems that SQLite3 doesn't support this functionality, as update hook functions only work when the database changes occur within the same process - which is not the case with various ROS nodes.

What should I try next? How is process data typically managed in larger ROS2 projects? Any recommendations or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What [QoS](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Concepts/Intermediate/About-Quality-of-Service-Settings.html#qos-policies) did you use for your `/parameter_events` topic? 

On paper, I'd think if you used something like `History: Keep All`, `Reliability: Reliable`, `Durability: Transient Local`, and perhaps a long `Lifespan`, you could avoid dropped messages.

Comment: A few other options to consider:

- if SQLite3 is more appropriate for complex data, then perhaps a hybrid approach where update "events" are announced via pubsub or as a service, simply listing the SQLite3 keys containing parameters that other nodes should update

- rather than having the centralized node use pub-sub, it could directly call the parameter update service of other nodes. If done asynchronously, this should also avoid dropping updates or blocking

But I can't speak towards the "best" or "typical" approach - it depends a lot on the system (e.g. network, how distributed, etc)

Comment: "I'm looking for a way to have a reactive callback whenever data changes" this was precisely one of our design goals with [Transitive](https://transitiverobotics.com/docs/learn/data_model#reading-and-changing-data).